# How can i create a view with content type but not basic page and article

Tags: view, drupal-8

I have created three content types

```
1)A form
2)B form 
3)C form
```

In total there are now 5 content types including

```
Basic page and article
```

Now i have created a view but all content types are allowed including page and article. I want to create a view using these three:

```
A form B form C form
```

Is there any way? I have checked but while creating view there is no multiple select for content type allowed?

Now

```
select
All
page
artcle
A form
B form
C form
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated, Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Edit your view and go to filter criteria.
Here you can add a filter for content types.

Example from the /admin/content view. Except you probably don't want to expose your filter to visitors in your case:
[image]